# Ubuntu 20.04 boots in > 100 seconds

Tags: boot, 20.04, plot

Updated to ubuntu 20.04, now, the boot time is ultra high.

Here is the [image](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vervaekejonathan/cda4db5259bc4ea49c1b825924dee27f/raw/bd0c5ea30ad112a8cd28e2f6eda85697354d03ef/boot.svg) generated from the boot analysis:

`➜ systemd-analyze plot > ~/SystemdAnalyzePlot.png`

What is stalling the boot time? Can't figure it out from this picture..

Comment: try `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: Looks like you have many snaps installed on your system. If you can, remove them or replace them with the .deb versions. See whether there is any improvement.